# My 16 gb is just showing 0.99 GB now

Tags: usb-flash-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix my USB drive to get its original 8GB size back?](https://superuser.com/questions/382242/how-do-i-fix-my-usb-drive-to-get-its-original-8gb-size-back)

[Please read this link first](https://superuser.com/questions/382242/how-do-i-fix-my-usb-drive-to-get-its-original-8gb-size-back)

My problem is the same as that described in the question here and I am also using a sandisk usb flash drive 16 GB. However I have no idea how to use bootice. can anyone please help?

Comment: -1 please elaborate where you are stuck, have you even tried to use it?

Comment: The answer even links to a tutorial on how to use BootIce…

Comment: I am sorry I wasnt more elaborate.

I have downloaded bootice but in the software, I cant understand a single thing. There's something about MBR but I have no experience in this area

Comment: Please ask specific answerable questions, SuperUser is a Q&A Site, not a forum. Have you read the guide, where did you fail?

Comment: Instead of linking to the other question and asking to elaborate on the answer, a comment on that answer is the best thing to do.  Unfortunately you don't have enough reputation (20) to do that just yet, but after a while you'll be able to do so.  Good luck.

Comment: Also related: [16 GB USB flash drive capacity down to 938 MB](//superuser.com/q/752874/354511), [Flash disk capacity turns from 32 GB to 4 MB](//superuser.com/q/937410/354511), [USB drive not showing full size](//superuser.com/q/88509/354511), [16 GB USB flash drive shows as 16 MB and is unusable](//superuser.com/q/50207/354511), [1 GB space left after formatting a 16 GB flash drive?](/q/339489/354511), [16 GB USB flash drive turned to 1 GB after writing an ISO image onto it](/q/759602/354511) and [Toshiba pen drive shows 4 MB instead of 8 GB; what could have happened to it?](/q/927680/354511)

Answer (score 1):

Your drive is possibly corrupt and/or defective. I had a similar problem on a drive that I had purchased off of eBay. If your using Windows, I would try following these steps:

> (Note: This will remove anything from your drive!)
>
> Go to Start --> Run --> type "cmd" --> Press Enter.
>
> Once the command prompt opens, type "diskpart" then hit Enter. Next you will need to type "list disk" and hit Enter. You will then see a list of disks beginning with Disk 0. Find the disk that corresponds with the usb drive.
>
> For this instance, say the usb drive is disk 1. Type "select disk 1" in the command prompt, hit Enter. You will then see a message that says Disk 1 is now the selected disk. I used disk 1 as just a reference, you need to type the disk number that actually corresponds to the usb drive.
>
> Next, type "Clean" in the command prompt, hit Enter. You should receive a message stating that the disk was cleaned.
>
> Now, type "create partition primary" in the command prompt, hit Enter. You should receive a message stating the specified partition was created.
>
> Now, type "active" in the command prompt, hit Enter. This sets the partition as active.
>
> Now, type "format fs=fat32" in the command prompt, hit Enter which will format the disk.
>
> Now you should be all set with a fresh usb stick with no errors. Once the format completes, the usb stick should work just fine.
>
> Now, just type exit to exit diskpart and then type exit again to exit the command prompt

If that doesn't work, then I am sorry to say but your drive is pouched. Hopefully you can return it to whoever you bought it from.

Comment: Actually it got fixed. There was this option in bootice to repartition the drive. I tried it and now its all fixed. :)

Comment: Hi @CodeRed. Please state your solution as an answer, so that you can accept it and close the question.

Comment: i cant do that for another 6 hours, thats some restriction they have for the new users. I will do it once the restrictions over! :)