# How to restore USB's full capacity?

Tags: windows-8, usb

My Toshiba 8 GB pen drive is showing it's capacity as 4 MB. I tried both BOOTICE and command line solutions mentioned at [How do I fix my USB drive to get its original 8GB size back?](https://superuser.com/questions/382242/how-do-i-fix-my-usb-drive-to-get-its-original-8gb-size-back/382250#382250?newreg=0b70c5167f4f432db97514ef4ba1045f) but neither of them worked.
I would be glad if someone helps me out in getting back my USB's original capacity.

Comment: What Operating System?

Comment: Please make a screenshot of Disk Management.

Comment: If it is not already answered: I'd recommend editing your question to describe what happened to make it lose capacity in the first place.

Comment: Open command prompt and type "chkdsk x:" replace "x" with the letter for your usb stick. What does it list for "total disk space", "available on disk", and "in bad sectors"? PLEASE NOTE THAT IF CHECK DISK FINDS ERRORS IT MAY ATTEMPT TO FIX THEM, IF UNSUCCESSFUL THIS CAN CAUSE DATA LOSS! SO IF YOU HAVE AN IMPORTANT DATA ON THE USB BACK IT UP FIRST. As suggested by others a screenshot of Disk Management would also be helpful. I know you don't have enough rep to post a picture, but add it, then deleted all but the url from your post before submit, and it will show up as a link that we can see.

Comment: Screenshots are available at https://www.dropbox.com/s/a4swvde87sswu8m/tb.jpg?dl=0, https://www.dropbox.com/s/gea785xmz090rth/tb1.png?dl=0. chkdsk disk didn't show any bad sectors.

Answer (score 1):

Going to take a stab here and say it's likely you simply need to repartition your thumb drive:

1. Right Click on the start menu(or lower left hand corner that brings metro up for 8.0)
2. Select Disk management.
3. In the window you should see 2 panes, the lower should show the physical disks in your drive.
4. Find the thumb drive (BE VERY CAREFUL IT IS YOUR THUMB DRIVE!!!!! To make sure you can unplug and plug it it to see it it disappears/appears).
5. Delete any named partitions on it by right clicking and selecting Delete Volume. ALL DATA WILL BE DESTROYED!!! SO BE CAREFUL!
6. In the unpartitioned space right click and create a new simple volume as either NTFS(less compatible with other OSs like Mac but faster) or FAT32 and assign it a drive letter in the wizard.

You can see more information about creating a new partition at [Microsoft TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg309170.aspx)

Comment: I've tried that earlier, 'Delete' option is unavailable(It's in Grey text).

Comment: scroll down to the bottom. You can't delete the system disk drives. Make sure your selecting the 8MB partition.

Answer (score -1):

Try this software. Let it analyse your usb and then try writing new headers / filesystem to it. Works on a lot of Operating Systems.

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

Comment: I have tried http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step, but it couldn't detect anything.

Comment: It can't detect your USB drive? The size of your disk? What do you mean, Naveen?

Comment: After "A partition is still missing: Deeper Search" it didn't go as  in documentation and if I keep on pressing "Enter" it is repeating a loop.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's hard for me to know exactly what you are experiecing, but this is one of the most powerful tools available. It seems you are trying to restore partitions. That's not what you should be doing. What you should be trying to do is to write a new header on your disk, which seems to be corrupt. And if you can't restore a system's ability to detect the correct size, then I would say your USB is broke.

Comment: There are lot of procedures in the link you have given. Please give   me the exact link to be followed.

Comment: Sorry, can't. Read the above again for the why. Good luck.