# How to get back my remaining capacity of my 8GB pendrive?

Tags: memory, 64-bit, usb-flash-drive

A few weeks ago, I inserted my pendrive into my college's PC to transfer my assignments, but it was not working. It was corrupted and was asking to format. I couldn't even copy files, and was forced to format.

After formatting, my pendrive's size was reduced from 8GB to 3.96MB.

Since then, I've been trying restore it. From `diskpart` to third-party software, Windows to Linux, watching several youtube videos, but nothing has worked.

I already have looked at [this question](https://superuser.com/q/382242/103134), but nothing worked.

PS: I'm using 64-bit system to achieve restoration.

Comment: Did you use the clean option in diskpart?

Comment: Also related: [16 GB USB flash drive capacity down to 938 MB](//superuser.com/q/752874/354511), [Flash disk capacity turns from 32 GB to 4 MB](//superuser.com/q/937410/354511), [USB drive not showing full size](//superuser.com/q/88509/354511), [16 GB USB flash drive shows as 16 MB and is unusable](//superuser.com/q/50207/354511), [1 GB space left after formatting a 16 GB flash drive?](/q/339489/354511), [16 GB USB flash drive turned to 1 GB after writing an ISO image onto it](/q/759602/354511) and [Toshiba pen drive shows 4 MB instead of 8 GB; what could have happened to it?](/q/927680/354511)

Answer (score 0):

**MiniTool Partition Wizard Free  - worked for me.**

I have an 8Gb USB flash drive that I'd previously formatted as bootable with MemTest95 on it. When I deleted MemTest95 and formatted it, it kept saying capacity was only 49Mb. I tried various solutions but none worked. Finally I recalled a great program I'd used in the past for creating partitions etc., and wondered if it would restore my USB Flash drive to full capacity. Thankfully, MiniTool worked a charm. Easy to use and fast.

Now have my USB Flash drive restored back to 8Gb. Very happy to recommend MiniTool Partition Wizard Free to anyone with this problem.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [SD Formatter](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/)? While its designed for SD card it also works on USB flash drive. Another possibility is that, something wrong with the controller and in this case you'll need a "USB Production" tool to fully restore the capacity(and block possible bad sectors), however you need to find the exact tool for your flash drive and might not worth the trouble.