# How to undo hack on fake memory card

Tags: memory, sd-card, memory-card

I bought an SD memory card 32gb that I didn't know was fake till I used it on my PSP, then I tested it with h2testw to know the actual capacity and it was way lower than 32gb,maybe about 4gb, please how do I restore the memory card back to the amount it can actually hold without corrupting data?

Comment: Possible dupe: [How do I fix my USB drive to get its original 8GB size back?](http://superuser.com/questions/382242/how-do-i-fix-my-usb-drive-to-get-its-original-8gb-size-back)

Comment: "how do I restore the memory card back to the amount it can actually hold without corrupting data?" - You can't.  It only can store 4 GB.  Are you asking how to make it display 4 GB capacity instead?  If that is the case, you can't, not without a way to modify the firmware on the device.

Answer (score 1):

If the memory card is fake and only stores about `4gb`, then it can't "go back" to `32gb` since it never had that much space to begin with. If it was partitioned, you could repartition and reformat.

[Check this answer for more information](https://superuser.com/a/382250/518805).

And to avoid losing the data on it, you'll need to back it up somewhere else BEFORE you reformat it.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I know it can't go back to 32 GB, what I was asking was about restoring it to its original space ie the 4gb, how do I do that?

Comment: If it isn't a fake or broken memory card, then you can just `reformat` it in most cases. If it's completely fake, then you unfortunately have to eat your loss.

Comment: Is there a difference between formatting and reformatting, because I've formatted the card a lot

Comment: They're the same thing. :) Although technically, you could format a blank hard drive, and all future formats would be a "reformat." Most people use both terms interchangeably, so everyone should be able to understand what you mean.

Comment: @Dipo Repartition it and then format it.

Comment: So the memory card is gone forever:(

Comment: How do I repartition?

Comment: Not necessarily. Like @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 and I said, you can try to repartition and then format it.

Comment: [How do I fix my USB drive to get its original 8GB size back?](http://superuser.com/questions/382242/how-do-i-fix-my-usb-drive-to-get-its-original-8gb-size-back)

Comment: Thanks guys, it didn't work, so the memory card is a legit fake, but thanks for the answers

Comment: "Reformatting" will not help. Reformatting simply tries to create a new file system within the number of blocks reported by the card. What is desired here is to change the number of blocks reported by the card. Reformatting or repartitioning will not do that. To get the card to report its true capacity you would have to modify the card firmware.

Comment: It was patronizing of you to assume he's so illogical that he thinks he can do what the maker couldn't and get the card going with 32gb... It's the reason I deleted my first SE account (it's a very snobbish environment). If you truly care about people, give them more credit. You aren't the only smart person on this planet!

Answer (score 1):

These fake-capacity cards are made with the poorest quality components, just good enough to store a limited amount of data for a short time. I would not trust any such card to store data reliably, even at its true tested capacity.

Your best bet therefore is to try to get a refund from the seller.

Your second best bet, for the same reason, is to throw the card away.