# Partially formatted flash drive

Tags: usb-flash-drive

i was formatting my flash drive when we randomly lost power and now i have a flash drive that is recognized as a device but not a drive. not recovering files just the drive itself. shows up in device manager but not computer.

Comment: so, did it work?

Answer (score 2):

Run an elevated command prompt session. Enter these commands.

```
    diskpart
    list disk
```

Select your disk. If you have one external drive plugged in it will be disk 1. If you have more than one external drive plugged in check disk management for you disk number.

```
    select disk 1
    clean
    create primary partition
```

These next two commands can be flipped.

```
    format fs=fat32 quick
    active
```

This next command will give the drive a drive letter

```
    assign
```

If you ever mess up during this just select the disk again, clean it, then repeat these commands

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will help [How do I fix my USB drive to get its original 8GB size back?](https://superuser.com/questions/382242/how-do-i-fix-my-usb-drive-to-get-its-original-8gb-size-back)

There is a tool from a flash hardware manufacturer which people who own boards like Raspberry Pi's use to regain the entire space of the ssd memory card. Maybe that tool will help.

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/restoring-your-usb-key-partition/

It is SD Formatter (https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/) If that doesn't help, then I don't know what will.