# Usb stick in system devices but not in drives after re-partitioning with BootIce

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, formatting, usb-storage

I had usb stick that was formatted as iso.

Today i tried to recover it's original size (by using Bootice) and it worked ok, but now I can only see stick in `System` -> `Disk Drives` but not in `Windows Explorer`

[image]

Disk is formatted

[image]

**How do I make usb stick appear in drives?**

Comment: Does this drive by chance more then a single partition?

Comment: I see it has a label in your application, double check by pressing Windows + R for run, type diskmgmt.msc, right click on the partition and assign a drive letter by clicking "Change Drive Letters and Paths"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out myself.

When formatting in Bootice I had selected `Start LBA 2048` [from this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/382242/how-do-i-fix-my-usb-drive-to-get-its-original-8gb-size-back#answer-382250).

I had to set it to `1` and reformat again to make it appear in Windows Explorer