# My 128GB USB Flash Disk have only 117 GB. How to format for 128GB?

Tags: usb, partitioning

I have 128GB SuperSonic Rage 2

[image]

and my pc shows only 117GB:

[image]

I tried to format with BOOTICE [from this answer](https://superuser.com/a/382250/761864) and then [from this answer](https://superuser.com/a/382249/761864). Still shows 117 GB.

Somewhere I read that USB calculate capacity 1GB = 1000MB and computer 1GB = 1024MB. If this is true, my capacity 117GB is wrong anyway because 128000MB / 1024 = **125GB**

Please help me give me back full size. Thank you!

Comment: The reported space is correct.  A file system has overhead additionally Windows doesn't report space in base 10.  What you have discovered is perfectly  normal

Comment: and is possible to delete file system data?

Comment: If you did that then you wouldn't be able to store anything on the drive because it would be unallocated space

Answer (score 6):

First of all, it's not enough to say that 1GiB = 1024 Mib and 1GB = 1000MB. You have to consider that this relation holds for smaller unit of measure, i.e.

```
1GiB = 1024MiB = 1024*1024KiB = 1024*1024*1024B = 2^30B
1GB  = 1000MB  = 1000*1000KB  = 1000*1000*1000B = 10^9B
```

So, the ratio `GiB/GB` is not `1000/1024=0.976` but `10^9/2^30= 0.931`. This drops down your storage significantly: `128GB = 119.2GiB`. That leaves aside a couple of GiB. These overhead is reserved for file-system usage purpose. You can not get rid of this space, whether you are using FAT32, exFAT or NTFS. It could change the size of the overhead, but it will remain there by all means.

Answer (score -1):

1. It is customary for storage manufacturers to state the capacity in decimal bytes. Which means that 1 GB = 1,000,000,000 bytes and not 1.073.741.824. Note the 7.5 % savings, which means that if this were the only reason, your stick would be 118.4 GB.
2. For flash devices they may include the backup sectors in that total, even if you cannot use them.
3. They lie on the true capacity anyway, because it's easier to sell a 128 GB stick than a 117.85 GB (or 129.32 GB) one.

Comment: Do you have any actual data or proof of them lying?

Comment: "They lie on the true capacity anyway" - This is false.  They disclose the how they came up with the size of the device on the box.  The fact the author of this question failed to read that disclosure does not mean the manufacture lied about the size of the device.

Comment: Tried `lsblk -b` with four storage units, advertized respectively as a 512GB SSD, 2TB HDD, 64GB USB stick, and a 32GB SD Card. SSD, HDD, and SD card were "decimally accurate", even if the SD card was a bit shy of the promised 32*10^9 bytes. The USB stick (Kingston Data Traveler) is only 62008590336 bytes. If it's not a lie, it's "alternate specs" because they don't count their gigabytes like the others.